# AWS Cognito Authentication successful but Authorization fail with .NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

**Environment**

- AWS Cognito user pool
- OIDC authentication
- ASP.NET Core identity model auth

**Problem Statement**

We have an already authenticated token got from Cognito (access, refresh, id). However, when we send the same token for user check, it gets *authenticated* successfully however *authorization* fails.

**Code & Config**

*Server*

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AuthenticationConfig.DefaultPolicy, policy =>
            {
                var defaultPolicy =
                    authConfig.Policies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == AuthenticationConfig.DefaultPolicy);
                foreach (var claims in defaultPolicy.Claim)
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(claims.Key, claims.Value);
                }
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = authConfig.Authority;
                options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                options.IntrospectionDiscoveryPolicy = new DiscoveryPolicy()
                {
                    EndpointValidationExcludeList = {"registration_endpoint"}
                };
            });
```

*Config*

```
 "AuthenticationConfig": {
   "Authority": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxx",
   "Policies": [
     {
      "Name": "Default",
      "Claim": {
         "MyAppNameGoesHere": [
             "MyClientNameGoesHere"
          ]
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

*Client*

```
        var token = $"Bearer {_credentialFileHandler.GetToken(CredentialFileHandler.AccessToken)}";
        var entries = new Metadata
        {
            {"api-version", GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()},
            {"Authorization", token},
        };

        if (metadata != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in metadata)
            {
                entries.Add($"app-{entry.Key}", entry.Value);
            }
        }

        _callInvoker = _channel.Intercept(m =>
        {
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                m.Add(entry);
            }

            return m;
        });
```

*Cognito Config on AWS*

[image: Cognito permission]

[image: OAuth setup]

**Result**

The authentication works successfully and user's login name gets logged (upon turning `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;`). However, the authorization still fails.

**Debugging attempts**

Any additional code/config etc can be provided as needed necessary for troubleshooting

**Update... More config**

The claim in the access token passed says "MyAppNameGoesHere\MyClientNameGoesHere", as returned by Cognito's Resource server configuration. The app server is requesting claim as given in the Authentication config above.
Let me know if the values are logically matching or if I am blatantly wrong somewhere.

Cloudwatch log [image: Cloudwatch log indicating failed authorization]

Comment: Without any error messages, all I can give you is a shot in the dark. In Startup#Conffigure, do you have app.UseAuthorization(); ?

Comment: Have you verified that the claims you require are in the token?

Comment: Yes Authorization is turned on in Startup. Not able to find a way to run on custom claims in Cognito which we want

Comment: @RoarS.added authorization details. please check

Comment: @Parsifal yes, added custom claim details in end of question, please check